# android emulator not increase storage

Tags: android, android-emulator, storage

I have about 20 Gb data for my application 
here i want to increase my storage.i want to download all in Internal stroage or SD card(external Storage) depending upon where is space for about 20 GB.i am currently i am checking app in android Emulator i am increasing space like bellow screen shot [image] but when i start emulator in storage i found not space increased [image] 
can any body tell what is problem and what wrong i am doing?
please help!!

Comment: 20GB app data ? OMG what you are saying! And you want to download it too.. Impossible pal..